# Which is better for the community: external fiddle or built in fiddle?

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

I just noticed SO allows you to add a code Snippet, which works like JSFiddle.

So, when making questions, would it be better to make a snippet in external editors like JS Fiddle and put a link to it in the question, or would it be better if we simply use the built in fiddler?

When I say better, I'm talking about making problem solving easier, make it less risky for the users, be safe that the fiddle won't be removed in future, etc.

Answer (score 11):

**Always, always, always** include the relevant code *in your question or answer*. Because of potential link-rot, posts are judged without the links to external resources.

This means that for all intents and purposes, external links **do not actually exist**. They are imaginary, a figment of your imagination. If you do not include the code in your question or answer, then the code isn't real.

That is not to say that you should never include links to external resources, that can be useful sometimes. But you should never *rely* on external resources for your question or answer.